# Weak$^*$ topology on Bochner $L^p$-spaces

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, duality

Assume that $X$ is a Banach space such that the dual $X'$ has the Radon-Nikodym property. Moreover let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ a say finite measure space. Then we know that for $1\leq p<\infty$ holds that
$$
L^p(\Omega,X)'\cong L^q(\Omega,X')
$$
where $q$ is the conjugate of $p$ (as it is known for $L^p$-spaces). Now let us fix $1\leq p<\infty$ (and hence also $q$). Then one can cosider the weak$^*$-topology on $L^q(\Omega,X')$. Now the question: is the following formulation true?

A sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ converges to $f$ in the weak$^*$-topology of $L^q(\Omega,X')$ if and only if
$$
\int_{\Omega}{||f_n(s)g(s)-f(s)g(s)||_X\ d\mu(s)}\rightarrow0,\ n\rightarrow\infty.
$$
for each $g\in L^p(\Omega,X)$. But that makes for me now sense because the how is the product defined and why can one just use the norm on $X$? So can you maybe give the good definition of the weak$^*$-topology on this space? Maybe it should be something like
$$
\int_{\Omega}{||f_n(s)-f(s)||_{X'}\cdot ||g(s)||_X\ d\mu(s)}
$$
for each $g\in L^p(\Omega,X)$? So can you please help me with this?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Is not $f(s)g(s)$ a real number? (You consider $X$-norm of it.)

Comment: @MikhailOstrovskii : But $f\in L^p(\Omega,X)$ which means that $f:\Omega\rightarrow X$, isn't it?

Comment: But the only meaning which I can attach to $f(s)g(s)$ is the action of the functional $f(s)\in X'$ on the vector $g(s)\in X$, and the result of this action is a number.